# Tensorflow Object Detection: ImportError: cannot import name 'inception_resnet_v2'

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow

When I train to train my model with the following command:

```
python train.py -logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_
rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 52, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\FrameCapture\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 35, in <module>
    from object_detection.models import faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor as frcnn_inc_res
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\FrameCapture\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\models\faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_feature_extractor.py"
, line 30, in <module>
    from nets import inception_resnet_v2
ImportError: cannot import name 'inception_resnet_v2'
```

I have noticed that under the nets directory, there is no file named 'inception_resnet_v2'. Here are all the 
[files under the nets directory.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPxHb.png)

I notice that if I change a file under the nets directory to have the name 'inception_resnet_v2', I am met with a new error about the nets directory:

```
  File "train.py", line 52, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import model_builder
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\FrameCapture\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 38, in <module>
    from object_detection.models import faster_rcnn_nas_feature_extractor as frcnn_nas
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Anaconda3\envs\FrameCapture\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\models\faster_rcnn_nas_feature_extractor.py", line 29, in <m
odule>
    from nets.nasnet import nasnet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nets.nasnet'
```

Because of this, I suspect the root of the problem comes from something to do with the nets directory. It might be worth noting that before this error, I was getting a ModuleNotFoundError because there was no nets directory under C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ObjectDetection\models\research\object_detection. I solved this by copying the nets directory from C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.8.egg\object_detection.

I can't find anything that I've neglected during the installation process. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried deleting and recreating the Conda environment?

Comment: After recreating the Conda environment, I still have the same issue. I have no idea why this could be happening but it's very disappointing and completely halting my work.

Answer (score 4):

You need to run the following:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<PATH_TO_TF>/TensorFlow/models/research
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<PATH_TO_TF>/TensorFlow/models/research/object_detection
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:<PATH_TO_TF>/TensorFlow/models/research/slim
```

`nets` exists locally but you have to add these paths in order for python to know it's there. Do not install `nets` yourself with pip, that package is not the one required.